# Find and print all overlapping k-mers

Tags: perl

I am trying to write a perl program that reads a fasta file and prints out a text file containing all available (overlapping) length 15 k-mers from the sequence (fasta) file. This program works perfectly fine when I'm searching for non-overlapping k-mers, but when I coded it to find overlapping k-mers, it takes forever for it to execute and Cygwin ended up killed program after 12 hours. (I left the match_count there to count the total, please feel free to ignore that line)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $k = 15;
my $input = 'fasta.fasta';
my $output = 'text.txt';
my $match_count = 0;

#Open File
unless (open(FASTA, "<", $input)){
    die "Unable to open fasta file", $!;
    }

    #Unwraps the FASTA format file
    $/=">";
    #Separate header and sequence
    #Remove spaces
unless (open(OUTPUT, ">", $output)){
die "Unable to open file", $!;
}

    while (my $line = <FASTA>){
            my($header, @seq) = split(/\n/, $line);
                    my $sequence = join '', @seq;

    while (length($sequence) >= $k){
        $sequence =~ m/(.{$k})/;
        print OUTPUT "$1\n";
        $sequence = substr($sequence, 1, length($sequence)-1);
    }
}
```

The result I am looking for is:

```
A total of 20938309 k-mers printed in the text file when I use the wc -l command.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you just looking for a total kmer count or do you need a file with all the kmers?

Comment: Generating about 20M substrings shouldn't take *that* long even though that loop isn't very efficient. How big (bytes and records) is your input file?
You could use the following for your last `while` loop to avoid a large amount of string modifications: `for my $i (0..length($sequence)-$k) {
    print OUTPUT substr($sequence, $i, $k), "\n";
}`

Comment: @ChrisCharley I need a file with all the kmers. I just need to use wc -l command to make sure that I have 20m kmers in total.

Comment: @mbethke I'm not exactly sure what's the size of the input file. But I am assuming the size should be greater than 20mb. And I tried your modification, but it still takes forever for the code to be executed.

Comment: On a 20,000 size fasta file I have on my computer, I generated almost 20,000 overlapping kmers.

Comment: @ChrisCharley I don't know why, but it is taking forever to execute the file. I do not know what is the exact file size, but it should be containing 20m kmers in total.

Comment: @mbethke Actually, I tried out your modification, it gave me 1 billion k-mers according to the wc -l command on Linux.

Comment: @Sunny: if the input is that big, you'll get quite a bit more than 20 million sequences; my wild-ass estimate (35,000 sequences of 500 bytes each) is about 255 million. Still nothing that should kill the process; on reasonably recent hardware it should be possible in a couple of minutes. You could try printing input record numbers to monitor progress.
Edit: OK, a billion sounds realistic; so it's working now?

Comment: @mbethke It's indeed executing a lot quicker than it used to be. Edit:I just found out why I accidentally made a typo and made it repeat endlessly. (Now fixed). However, I'm getting 23m k-mers instead of 20m (the expected amount).

Comment: The number of overlapping k-mers in a sequence is `length($sequence)-$k+1`, so you could easily calculate it for every record. E.g. in your read loop `printf "Sequence length is %d; generating %d k-mers of length %d (%d bytes total)", length($sequence), length($sequence)-$k+1, $k, (length($sequence)-$k+1)*$k;`

Comment: @mbethke Thank you very much for the help. I can understand the concept in your code. I'm just surprised how there are 2m extra k-mers appearing in my text file; and I am trying to figure out what I have done wrong.

Comment: One problem that may be adding the number of kmers too high (23M instead of 20M), you should `chomp $line` to remove the `>` at the end of the line (your input record separator). Although, that may not entirely account for the extra 2M.

Comment: @ChrisCharley The chomp doesn't make any difference, as I've removed the `>` with `$/=">";`. Thanks for the advise.

Comment: That doesn't remove it. The statement`$/=">";` just sets the input record separator, (`$/`), to `>`. So it reads one chunk (sequence) at a time. It is still necessary to remove it.

Comment: @ChrisCharley I see. It still shows the same amount of k-mers, so I am not sure what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why you're not getting your desired results.

I thought I'd post the 2 programs I've used following your problem description.

The first one just counts the kmers in a file I used for testing, (`fasta_dat.txt`). It doesn't print them out but is just a check to see how many kmers there are.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Bio::SeqIO;

my $in  = Bio::SeqIO->new( -file   => "fasta_dat.txt" ,
                           -format => 'fasta');

my $count_kmers;
my $k = 15;
while ( my $seq = $in->next_seq) {
    $count_kmers += $seq->length - $k + 1;
}

print $count_kmers;

__END__
C:\Old_Data\perlp>perl t9.pl
18657
```

You can see the count (after the `__END__` token), 18657. This count agreed with the count of the kmers when I printed them out using your code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.014;
use Devel::Size 'total_size';

my $k = 15;
my $input = 'fasta_dat.txt';
my $output = 'kmers.txt';
my $match_count = 0;

#Open File
unless (open(FASTA, "<", $input)){
    die "Unable to open fasta file", $!;
    }

    #Unwraps the FASTA format file
    $/=">";
    #Separate header and sequence
    #Remove spaces
unless (open(OUTPUT, ">", $output)){
    die "Unable to open file", $!;
}

<FASTA>; # discard 'first' 'empty' record

my %seen;
while (my $line = <FASTA>){
    chomp $line;
    my($header, @seq) = split(/\n/, $line);
    my $sequence = join '', @seq;

    for my $i (0 .. length($sequence) - $k) {
        my $kmer = substr($sequence, $i, $k);
        print OUTPUT $kmer, "\n" unless $seen{$kmer}++;
    }
}
print total_size(\%seen);
```

**Update** Tests I ran showed about a 100 times increase in memory for the hash size. The number of kmers in my test were about 18500. That resulted in a hash size of 1.8MB.

For your data, with kmers of 22M, would result in a hash size ~ 2.2GB. Don't know if this would exceed your memory capacity.

Comment: I tested out your code, it's also giving my 23m k-mers, exactly the same as the one I wrote. I am assuming that the extra 2m k-mers comes from 'repeated' k-mers (k-mers of exactly same sequence).

Comment: Is there a way to make it print out only distinct k-mers? Thanks.

Comment: @Sunny, I edited my code to eliminate duplicate kmers and the results show about 10% less kmers (w/o the duplicates).

Comment: I do not have the Devel::Size module here. Is there a standard perl way of doing it? Thanks.

Comment: @Sunny You don't need that module for your program. I had it in there so that I could measure the size of the `%seen` hash. (That last line is included in the code above)

Comment: I see! It works perfectly fine now, it takes a bit longer to execute, but it has the exact amount of kmers shown as expected result. May I ask one more question, if I want to count the total number of each distinct kmer, how would I add the code to it? Thanks.

Comment: From the command line, `perl -0 -ne "print tr/\n//" kmers.txt`